# How can I set mysql db as the default db for mongooseim

Tags: mongoose-im

I provide a mysql database name by creating database only (like mongoosedb) and change the ejabberd.cfg file accordingly . After restart mongooseim i still not get user entries in database. So what i will need to do to configure mysql as default database.

There is my ejabberd conf file:

```
%%
%% MySQL server:
%%
 {odbc_server, {mysql, "localhost", 3306, "mongooseim", "chat", "chat"}}.
%%
```

There is my db:

```
MariaDB [mongooseim]> show tables;
+----------------------+
| Tables_in_mongooseim |
+----------------------+
| last                 |
| mam_config           |
| mam_message          |
| mam_muc_message      |
| mam_server_user      |
| offline_message      |
| privacy_default_list |
| privacy_list         |
| privacy_list_data    |
| private_storage      |
| roster_version       |
| rostergroups         |
| rosterusers          |
| users                |
| vcard                |
| vcard_search         |
+----------------------+
```

Comment: I have this error in ejabberd log :
2016-05-06 02:46:10.344 [error] <0.955.0>@ejabberd_odbc:log:754 mysql_conn: Received unknown signal, exiting : {mysql_recv,<0.956.0>,closed,normal}

Comment: You have to set the database backend for each `mod_*` module from the `modules` section based. Not all modules require a database, though.

Comment: I change the auth_method to odbc and now I can see my newly created users in mysql users table, but I still can't see the message data in my db !!